# Login-AzureRmAccount wont log in using PSCredential

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am writing a PowerShell script to be able to access my Azure account. From the PowerShell command line, I can type Login-AzureRmAccount, manually enter my login information, and details of my account then display in the terminal inside PowerShell. However, if I try to make the script do the same thing, I get the following error:

[image]

And here is my code. Commented out is other ways i have tried so far.

```
# Credential Section
$azureAccountName ='login info here'
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString 'pass here' -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAccountName, $azurePassword)
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred

#$tenantId = "tenant id here"
#$login = "login info here"
#$login1 = 'login info here'
#$pass1 = 'pass here'
#Create Credentials
#$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString 'pass here' -AsPlainText –Force 
#$cred = New-Object -TypeName pscredential –ArgumentList $login1, $pass1
#Automate Future Logins
#Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred #-ServicePrincipal –TenantId $tenantId 

$Subscription = Select-AzureSubscription -Default -SubscriptionName "sub info here"
$StorageAccountName = Get-AzureStorageAccount –StorageAccountName "account name here"
$StorageAccountKey = (Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName).Primary
$context = New-AzureStorageContext $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey -SubscriptionName $Subscription 
Write-Output $context
```

I entered the login and pass manually when i typed Login-AzureRmAccount into the terminal but the script doing the same thing would not login. Any thoughts?

Comment: I use your script test in my lab. It works for me. I want to know what your account type? Microsoft account such as *.outlook.com *@hotmail.com? If possible, I suggest you check your Azure Powershell version. You could use this cmdlet `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh` to list version.

Comment: Any errors? "It just doesn't work" is not helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a microsoft account like - outlook/hotmail account, it is bound to throw errors like the above. This is how Azure AD is designed. Please use any org account or create your own Azure AD and use the user credentials of that Azure AD to login using the "Login-AzureRMAccount".

Answer (score 0):

These commands work for me

```
# Credential Section
$azureAccountName ="aaa@edmistorm.onmicrosoft.com"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "aaaaaabbb" -AsPlainText -Force

$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAccountName, $azurePassword)

Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred


$Subscription = Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId 6f1ac837-2c76-4fd2-b6ce-8b991a0dec0ad
```

[image: Output]
You may want to follow this thread as well
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1309